# Scala Polymorphism

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I have the following code:

```
trait SuperX {
 val v: Int
}

class SubY(val v: Int, var z: SuperX) extends SuperX

class SubZ(val v: Int) extends SuperX
```

and I don't understand why this is not possible

```
var test: SuperX = new SubY(1, new SubZ(-1))
println(test.z.v)
```

If I write it as

```
var test = new SubY(1, new SubZ(-1))
```

then I am not able to do

```
test = test.z
```

I'm new to Scala, so some things are quite confusing.
I know it's possible in Java with an interface instead of a trait.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you do in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
var test: SuperX = new SubY(1, new SubZ(-1))
```

You're explicitly telling the compiler that `test` is a `SuperX`. And the type `SuperX` is not guaranteed to have `z`, even if this particular instance does.

When you write:

```
var test = new SubY(1, new SubZ(-1))
```

The type of `test` is inferred as `SubY`, which does have `z`, so calling `test.z` is okay.

Comment: How would you change the structure of the program to be able to say test = test.z? In the latter case you can call test.z but not assign it to test (as the type of test is SubY). Ideally I would like test to be of type SuperX, and I would like to have the possibility of assigning it to one of its subclasses (either SubY or SubZ). When the assignment is successful, then I would like to call some of its fields (which only occur in the subclass, z in case of SubY).

Comment: You can't without using type tests. `SuperX` could also be `SubZ` which does not have `z`, so you could never just call `test.z` (if it has type `SuperX`), without first verifying that it is `SubY`. For instance by pattern matching on `test` for `SubY`, but that will still force you to handle the case when it is `SubZ`.

Comment: OK, but isn't it the purpose of polymorphism to be able to do so? I would be able to do it in Java this way. That's why Scala's way is so confusing to me.

Comment: No.. you shouldn't be able to do it in Java either without down-casting, which isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

The REPL will tell what is the resulting type after invoking:

```
scala> var test = new SubY(1, new SubZ(-1))
```

This will show that the inferred type reference is `SubY` and not `SuperX` as you expected.  Scala does inferred types if you do not provide one.  Your first example you explicitly declared it as `SuperX`

```
test: SubY = SubY@7ee12d58
```

Therefore the only methods and variables you can call are those of `SubY`